# Como añadir imagenes tipo BLOB a una tabla en MySQL Worbrench

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, redes-sociales

Hola tengo un problema que es que no se como insertar una imagen tipo BLOB en una tabla llamada usuario que e creado en mysql worbrench, la tabla es la siguiente

```
create table user
 (
 login varchar(100) primary key not null,
 correo_electronico varchar(300),
 contraseña varchar (25) not null,
 nombre_completo varchar(100) not null,
 imagen_fondo blob,
 imagen_personal blob,
 numero_visitas_perfil int,
 nick varchar(25),
 ciudad varchar(100),
 pais varchar(100),
 creado_en datetime
 );
```

Quiero insetar una imagen que es la foto de perfil y otra de fondo, en fin espero vuestra ayuda porque no e encontrado nada en internet, saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes usar `LOAD_FILE` ([aquí un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14704709/5587982)). Aunque sería mucho mejor guardar en la BD solamente la ruta, nombre y extensión de la imagen en una columna `VARCHAR`, y las imágenes tenerlas en archivos. Así, la BD es más portable y por otra parte los archivos podrías usarlos para otras cosas, por ejemplo, si necesitaras mostrarlos en algún contexto que no tenga nada que ver con la BD.

Comment: te lo acabo de poner la solución ahora solo lo debes adaptar a todas tus tablas.

Answer (score 0):

Como te han comentado si quieres guardar una imagen en una base de datos se usa el `LOAD_FILE`

***Por ejemplo :***

Si cogemos de la ***tabla `user`*** y ***tu columna `imagen_fondo`*** con el ***dato tipo `blob`*** pues para añadir una imagen a esa columna seria de la siguiente manera :

```
INSERT INTO user (imagen_fondo) VALUES (LOAD_FILE('rutacompletadetuimagen.png'));
```